# User registration form error php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi am trying to write code that validates in the backend. The code should stop as soon as there is an error. In my case, even if the conditions are satisfied the code stops in the first name validation block itself.
Also I wish to have only backend validation.

Here is the php code clientRegister.php

```
<?php

  require_once("connection.php");
  session_start();
// define variables and set to empty values

$clientFirstName = $clientLastName =$clientEmail = $clientPassword = 
$clientCPassword = $clientContact = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


    // First Name Validation
  if (empty($_POST["clientFirstName"])) {

    die("error: empty field");
  } else {
    $clientFirstName = test_input($_POST["clientFirstName"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("[a-zA-Z ]",$clientFirstName)) {

      die("Error: Only letters and white space allowed");

    }
  }

  // Last Name Validation

    if (empty($_POST["clientLastName"])) {


  die("error: empty field");

   } else {

  $clientLastName = test_input($_POST["clientLastName"]);

  // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

  if (!preg_match("[a-zA-Z ]",$clientLastName)) {


  die("Error: Only letters and white space allowed");
}

    }



    // Email Validation

   if (empty($_POST["clientEmail"])) {



   die("error: empty field");

   } else {

   $clientEmail = test_input($_POST["clientEmail"]);

  // check if e-mail address is well-formed

  if (!filter_var($clientEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {


  die("Error: Invalid email format");

  }

  }


  // Password Validation

  if (empty($_POST["clientPassword"])) {


  die("error: empty field");

  } 


  // Confirm Password Validation

  if (empty($_POST["clientCPassword"])) {


  die("error: empty field");

  } 


  if ($clientPassword != $clientCPassword) {

  die("error: passwords mismatch");


  }else{


  $hashedClientPassword = password_hash($clientPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 


  }


  if (empty($_POST["clientContact"])) {


  die("error: empty field");

  } else {

  $clientContact = test_input($_POST["clientContact"]);

  // check if number is correct

  if (!preg_match("[0-9]",$clientContact)) {

  die("error: Only 0-9 allowed");
  }

  }


  $check_email = $conn->query("SELECT clientEmail FROM tbl_clients WHERE 
  clientEmail='$clientEmail'");

  $emailCount=$check_email->num_rows;


  if ($emailCount==0) {


  $newClient = "INSERT INTO tbl_clients(clientFirstName, clientLastName, 
  clientEmail, clientPassword, clientContact) VALUES('$clientFirstName','$clientLastName','$clientEmail','$hashedClientPassword','$clientContact')";

if ($newClient === false){

    $result = array();
    $result[] = array("status" => "Error");
  }else{
     echo "Your have been signed up - please now Log In";


     $result = array();
     $result[] = array("First Name" => $clientFirstName, "Last Name" => $clientLastName, "Email" => $clientEmail, "Password" => $hashedClientPassword, "Contact" => $clientContact, "status" => "success");

  } 


  }else {

echo "Already Exists";
   $result = array();
    $result[] = array("status" => "Error");


    }


  echo json_encode($result);


  }


  function test_input($data) {

   $data = trim($data);

   $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;

  }


  ?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>  

<h2>Reg User</h2>
<form method="post" action="clientRegister.php">
      <label>
        First Name:<input type="text" name="clientFirstName"><br/>
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="clientLastName"><br/>
        Email:<input type="text" name="clientEmail"><br/>
        Password:<input type="password" name="clientPassword"><br/>
        Confirm Password:<input type="password" name="clientCPassword"><br/>
        Contact:<input type="text" name="clientContact"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">
      </label>
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the outcome from `var_dump($_POST["clientFirstName"]);` ?

Comment: to debug var_dump($_POST) like @James said, on clientRegister.php to check which variables are set and what their values are. Verify that all variable names are spelled right

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: just do away with that `test_input()` method and use a prepared statement. It's probably part of the root of this problem.

Comment: You also never executed that `$newClient` query, so I'm voting this as a typo, all 'round.

Comment: `if ($newClient === false)` doesn't nothing really.

Comment: Completely off topic. But in the future try using Exceptions and then handle them accordingly rather than using die() :) Also try using isset() rather than isEmpty().

Comment: try this: if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z ]/",$clientFirstName)){}

Comment: Can you please provide your test data and the result you're getting (ie screenshot), it will help us to debug your code.

Comment: my code doesnot proceed for last name validation even if first name validation doesnt have any errors. it dies with message "die("Error: Only letters and white space allowed");"

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d435ae025dc9e22b677823ff37712bb712b71e1b

Comment: @NavedShaikh that is exactly what you are doing in your code, if the `firstname` is correct, it will proceed and die on the `lastname` check if the lastname is not-correct. You should really function all of these procedures out to make it less complicated to follow and debug. For this code to execute and not produce any errors, you need to have all fields (firstname, lastname, email and others) to be all valid - and only then it will do the database stuff.

Comment: Check out this link: https://lzone.de/examples/PHP%20preg_match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing [pattern delimiters](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html) for your preg_match()

Replace your patterns with following sample:

```
if (!preg_match("[a-zA-Z ]",$clientFirstName)) {

    die("Error: Only letters and white space allowed");

}
```

With:

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z ]/",$clientFirstName)) {

    die("Error: Only letters and white space allowed");

}
```

Also your

```
($clientPassword != $clientCPassword)
```

will always return false because you have not assigned new $_POST values to them. And since you have initialized both variables as empty. So (empty != empty) always return false.

So you should compare like this:

```
($_POST["clientPassword"] != $_POST["clientCPassword"])
```

Regarding your query, it was not executed

```
$newClient = "INSERT INTO tbl_clients(clientFirstName, clientLastName, clientEmail, clientPassword, clientContact) VALUES('$clientFirstName','$clientLastName','$clientEmail','$hashedClientPassword','$clientContact')";
```

Which I think you meant:

```
$newClient = $conn->query("INSERT INTO tbl_clients(clientFirstName, clientLastName, clientEmail, clientPassword, clientContact) VALUES('$clientFirstName','$clientLastName','$clientEmail','$hashedClientPassword','$clientContact')");
```

**Note**: Your queries are vulnerable to sql injection and you should use [prepare statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

DEMO:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d435ae025dc9e22b677823ff37712bb712b71e1b

You can test this file:

https://pastebin.com/AgfquEMC

Comment: Tried not helping. It still dies even if only alphabets are used

Comment: Did you check my demo and see the difference? I have tested your script except your mysql query with the correction and it works fine here. So please check your implementation again.

Comment: yup I even edited if else to check  here is the updated code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8601cfbb43a8f6dbeef1a3d9e93177d78a35488

Comment: @NavedShaikh the code with at the link you have provided above contains a few syntax errors. I totally agree with Michael it is your implementation. Here have a look at the updated code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b21f91271d9f5ee767abd0d89a29ef3cb8e21eac -  all works (except for the db part). Also as I said before, function everything out, otherwise it is too coupled and thus causing you this headache.

Comment: Thx Max Maxymenko, it took me quite awhile to make this: https://pastebin.com/AgUZcnRb

Comment: thank you max maxymenko, But if you check the passwords dont match still it proceeds. it doesnt die.

Comment: @MaxMaxymenko could you please also check why it is proceeding even if password and confirm password donot match

Comment: Coz you are comparing $clientPassword != $clientCPassword without assigning new values to them. And you have initialized both as empty. So (empty != empty) returns false

Comment: thanks alot @MichaelEugeneYuen also can you guide me why will my db part wont work? I have connection.php file created also a db created on my localhost.

Comment: I have already given you my best advice regarding the question. If you have database connection issue. Please create a new post. Your question is "even if the conditions are satisfied the code die ". Please accept the answer so we can consider issue solved.

Comment: I hope whoever downvoted my answer can give me a reason

Comment: Naved Shaikh, please check my updated answer regarding your query

Comment: @NavedShaikh, I agree with Michael, create a new post regarding your issue with the database connection, but only concentrate on the database part, not the data validation which was the main focus in this post.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen totally agree with you, some people just down-vote for no particular reason... would be nice to see who actually did it if stack-overflow had such a feature.

Comment: It's okay. I just want to improve the quality of the answer if I deserve such downvote :)

Comment: Also @NavedShaikh, when writing any kind of SQL queries (select, update, insert, etc...) you should be using `prepared statements` - they prevent your code from being vulnerable to the SQL-Injection attacks!

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Thanks alot Sir! Your help is appreciated